# Issue Tensorflow 2.2 with model.fit and model.evaluate

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

When I whant to train my model in tf it seems like tf don't get right values **(cf [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJ18r.png)).**

I expect to have 21759 and not 680

It's appening since I changed of OS (fedora 30 xfce -> fedora 32 gnome) and on others laptops there is not this issue.


I am using Tf 2.2.

My dataset is made by somes csv created by tshark: [A screen of my DS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKE31.png)

Here is few lines of my code:

My model:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(9, input_shape=dataset[0].shape, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))

model.add(LSTM(9, input_shape=dataset[0].shape, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))

model.add(Dense(9, activation='relu'))
model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-4, decay=1e-5)

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
             optimizer=opt,
             metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Do you have any ideas ?

PS: It happens too with this .PY

```
import tensorflow as tf

dataset = [[1, 1],[2, 2]] * 50
label  = [0, 1] * 50

print(len(dataset))

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="relu", input_shape=(2,)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation="softmax")
])
model.compile(
    loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
    optimizer="sgd",
    metrics=["accuracy"]
)
history = model.fit(dataset, label, epochs=1)
```

Ouput:

```
100
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 611us/step - loss: 0.6578 - accuracy: 0.5000
```

Comment: Does your dataset use `batches` ?

Comment: What values were you expecting? Where is your code? What is your data?

Comment: My dataset does use batches @KoralpCatalsakal

Comment: Then, `680` could be the iteration count. In each iteration, the model processes `batch_size` of data instances.  So batch_size * 680 would be the total number of training instances(Assuming no overlap or replication)

Comment: Well that what I thought but with a totally differente model and dataset I have the same issue, and with the same notebook but with an other laptop I do not have this issue. @KoralpCatalsakal

Comment: I am not sure about the difference between the laptops, could be a configuration difference.
For the PS: Default `batch_size` for the `fit` is `32`, so that's why you have 4 iterations in one epoch. Similarly, if you use default batch size, 680*32 = 21760

Answer (score 0):

Like  Koralp Catalsakal said it was just an "configuration difference" issue.
So I just had to set up manually the batch_size.